# Display virtual adapters in network settings

Tags: network, big-sur, parallels-desktop

I've configured a host only adapter in Parallels Desktop. If I type `ifconfig` in the terminal that network adapter is listed in the output like:

```
...
bridge101: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether fa:ff:c2:xx:xx:xx 
    inet 192.168.12.98 netmask 0xffffffe0 broadcast 192.168.12.127
    inet6 fe80::c67:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%bridge101 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x14 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en11 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 19 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en12 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 21 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en13 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 22 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en14 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 23 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en16 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 25 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
    ...
```

Before I've upgraded to Big Sur, I was able to see those adapters also in the (visual) network settings of OSX. Now it is not listed there anymore. Is there a way to show them also in Big Sur?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the answer in the Parallels knowledge base (https://kb.parallels.com/125286):

> **Issue**
> After upgrading macOS to Big Sur, Connect Mac to this network
> and Show in System Preferences options disappeared from Parallels
> Desktop preferences > Network..
>
> Show in System Preferences option can not be selected so Host-Only
> network cannot be found from macOS System Preferences > Network.
>
> **Cause**
> These features are now hidden due to macOS Big Sur restrictions
> (KEXT-less network mode): In macOS Big Sur Apple restricted usage of
> kernel extensions and Parallels Desktop does not load them by default,
> instead it uses macOS own built-in mechanism.
>
> **Workaround**
> Downgrade to [Parallels Desktop 16.0.1](https://download.parallels.com/desktop/v16/16.0.1-48919/ParallelsDesktop-16.0.1-48919.dmg) or earlier - make
> sure the version is [compatible](https://kb.parallels.com/114381) with macOS Big Sur.